# Karatsuba Algorithm without BigInteger in Java, unexpected behaviour while recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, math, karatsuba

So I want to run Karatsuba Algorithm without using class BigInteger in Java, so upon following the pseudo-code and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531042/karatsuba-algorithm-without-biginteger-usage), I came with the following code

```
public static long recKaratsuba(long i1, long i2){

        if(i1<10 || i2<10) {
            return i1*i2 ;
        }

        long len = Math.round(Long.toString(Math.max(i1,i2)).length());
        long N  = Math.round(len/2) ;


        long b = (long) (i1% Math.pow(10, N)) ;
        long a = (long) (i1/ Math.pow(10,N));
        long d = (long) (i2% Math.pow(10,N)) ;
        long c = (long) (i2/ Math.pow(10,N));

        //System.out.println("a,b,c,d :" + a + b + c + d);



        long ac = recKaratsuba(a, c) ;
        long bd = recKaratsuba(b, d) ;
        long pos = recKaratsuba(a+b,c+d) ;

        return ((long)(bd + ac*Math.pow(10,len) + (pos -ac -bd)*Math.pow(10,N) )) ;
    }
```

Now, the problem with this is that it's producing the wrong answer, 1234*5678 is giving 11686652, which should've been 7006652.
As a beginner to Java and algorithms, I am unable to pinpoint the exact bug in this code, also I do realize that this program is very inefficient and doesn't work for more than 4 digits (according to the linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531042/karatsuba-algorithm-without-biginteger-usage) ). But this is intuitively what I came up with originally after learning the pseudo-code.

So my question is, what is the problem in my code and how do I execute the following algorithm without using the BigInteger method?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things i notice:

- Instead of *i1* and *i2* maybe use *x* and *y*
- Variables *len* and *N* are int, not long
- No need to round the maximum of the lengths of the string-representations: Lengths are ints, ints are whole numbers and cant be rounded
- No need to round the division by 2: Dividing a whole number will always result in a whole number (integer division is done)
- The error is in the return-statement: `Math.pow(10, len)` should be  `Math.pow(10, 2 * N)` instead, this is important if *N* is uneven
- Avoid multiple identical calculations: especially `Math.pow(10, N)`

The fixed code gives the correct results for all examples that i have tested.

```java
    public static long recKaratsuba2(long x, long y) {
        if (x < 10 || y < 10) {
            return x * y;
        }

        int len = Long.toString(Math.max(x, y)).length();
        double den = Math.pow(10, len / 2);
        long a = (long) (x / den);
        long b = (long) (x % den);
        long c = (long) (y / den);
        long d = (long) (y % den);

        long ac = recKaratsuba2(a, c);
        long bd = recKaratsuba2(b, d);
        long pos = recKaratsuba2(a + b, c + d);

        return (long) (bd + den * (ac * den + (pos - ac - bd)));
    }
```